# Parse string from Windows batch file

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file

I want to be able to check whether or not Tomcat is currently already running as a service.  The problem is that I'm not sure what the name of the service will be.
I plan to look in another batch file from where Tomcat is started.

In that file there is the line:

```
@echo off
rem START or STOP Tomcat
....
sc start "TomcatService5"
```

Is there an easy way to read that file and parse out the service name argument passed into the command "sc start"?

Comment: What language do you want to be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code searches for the line `sc start` in the file `start.cmd` and gets the 3rd token from that line:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr /L "sc start" start.cmd') do echo %%a
```